# Is it possible to change the shape of the material design slider? Android, Kotlin

Tags: android, material-ui, slider, material-design, material-components-android

The [slider by material design](https://m3.material.io/components/sliders/overview) has by default a pill shape. Is it possible to change that shape to a rectangle?

This is my goal. Green is the background, purple is 10% of progress, black is the 90% of unused progress.

[image: goal]

The ultimate goal is to add up multiple sliders into one widget that is a detailed audio level meter, for an audio mixer app.

[image: example]